# Use Generics for Return Type and Parameter

Tags: c#, generics

I am writing a lot of unit tests and due to the specifics of our framework, each one needs this mock which uses `DbSet` and some type. The only difference is the type, so I would like to avoid repeating the same method many times and if possible have one (maybe) generic method.
Using EF 6, .Net 4.7.1

Here is what I have now:

```
private Mock<DbSet<MyClass>> MockSetupForDbSet(List<MyClass> expected)

    {

        var mockDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<MyClass>>();



        mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<MyClass>>()

            .Setup(m => m.Provider)

            .Returns(new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<MyClass>(expected.AsQueryable().Provider));



        mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<MyClass>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(expected.AsQueryable().Expression);



        return mockDbSet;

    }
```

And this is what I need:

```
private Mock<DbSet<T>> MockSetupForDbSet(List<T> expected) where T : class

    {

        var mockDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();



        mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>()

            .Setup(m => m.Provider)

            .Returns(new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<T>(expected.AsQueryable().Provider));



        mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(expected.AsQueryable().Expression);



        return mockDbSet;

    }
```

Is this the proper way or should I use another approach, e.g. `dynamic` parameter?

----- EDIT -----

Here is the final version of the generic method, thanks to the help from StackOverflow members (in case it helps someone in future):

```
internal static Mock<DbSet<T>> MockSetupForDbSet<T>(List<T> expected) where T : class

        {

            var mockDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();



            mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>()

                .Setup(m => m.Provider)

                .Returns(new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<T>(expected.AsQueryable().Provider));



            mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(expected.AsQueryable().ElementType);



            mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(expected.AsQueryable().GetEnumerator());



            mockDbSet.As<IDbAsyncEnumerable<T>>()

                .Setup(m => m.GetAsyncEnumerator())

                .Returns(new TestDbAsyncEnumerator<T>(expected.GetEnumerator()));



            mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(expected.AsQueryable().Expression);



            return mockDbSet;

        }
```

The test is written based and depends on Microsoft documentation 'Testing with a mocking framework":
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/mocking#async

Comment: You forgot to actually add the `T` type parameter in the definition

Comment: Which EF framework are you using? What are you trying to test? EF Core's [in-memory provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory) is probably a better option for testing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include the generic type argument

```
                                This
                                 |
                                 V
Mock<DbSet<T>> MockSetupForDbSet<T>(List<T> expected) where T : class {
    //...omitted for brevity
}
```

provided the function is not already part of a generic class

```
class MyClass<T> {
    Mock<DbSet<T>> MockSetupForDbSet(List<T> expected) where T : class {
        //...omitted for brevity
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome...first of all, I am happy that this works perfect and second that this was so simple adjustment. Very appreciated!